# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule' could not be found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob, ads, expo-go

i create expo go react native project .
import { AppOpenAd, InterstitialAd, RewardedAd, BannerAd, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';  then shwoing this error

then showing error [shwoing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD8cg.png)

error is :

```
 Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","SourceCode","Timing","AppState","BlobModule","WebSocketModule","DevSettings","DevToolsSettingsManager","Networking","Appearance","DevLoadingView","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","DeviceInfo","UIManager","DeviceEventManager"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","RedBox","BugReporting","RNGoogleMobileAdsModule"]}, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "admobads",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~50.0.13",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.10",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.5",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^13.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppOpenAd, InterstitialAd, RewardedAd, BannerAd, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
   
  },
});
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Admobads",
    "slug": "Admobads",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.sonikaran12345.Admobads"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "1e6d9017-9f63-xxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxx~1xxx"
   
  }
}
```

i add all deatail now how i solved this error any one solved this error

Comment: I've the same error. Have you resolved it? How? Thakns Max

Comment: yes i resolved this error use expo development build